# Displaying Milliseconds of the current time

Tags: matlab

I am trying to display the milliseconds of the current time on screen but I couldn't do it. I managed to show only the seconds .. any help??

My Code:

```
datestr(now, 'HH:MM:SS')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the second-to-last row of the [format out table](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datestr.html#inputarg_formatOut), you need the `FFF` identifier:

```
>> datestr(now, 'HH:MM:SS:FFF')

ans =
19:35:59:476
```

Answer (score 2):

> just add `'FFF'` for Millisecond in three digits

```
datestr(now,'HH:MM:SS.FFF')
```